# How to search in a Javascript Object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm using Angular 2 here with Typescript.

I have an array of objects which looks like this;

```
lists: any [] = [
{title: 'Title1', content: 'Content1', id: 10},
{title: 'Title2', content: 'Content2', id: 13},
{title: 'Title3', content: 'Content3', id: 14},
{title: 'Title4', content: 'Content4', id: 16},
];
```

All I'm trying to do is that I need a true or false value returned after finding a particular id in the array.

I found an example with strings which is below.

```
myFunction() {
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
var d = a >= 0 ? true : false
console.log(d);
}
```

But when I apply this in my situation, it didn't work.

Comment: Please show us your logic to search for object in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`Array#find`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwju6Z2njJrUAhXGso8KHRvrDEIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffind&usg=AFQjCNEJXKz25jH7wLT1dX55f_XDZ9QiRg&sig2=DjtwVVCDsz_MXJyA0uMxLA)  method

```js
var a= [
{title: 'Title1', content: 'Content1', id: 10},
{title: 'Title2', content: 'Content2', id: 13},
{title: 'Title3', content: 'Content3', id: 14},
{title: 'Title4', content: 'Content4', id: 16},
];

function check(id){
return a.find(a=> a.id == id) ? true : false;
}

console.log(check(10))
console.log(check(105))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
let containsId => id => item => item.id === id;
let isIdInList = lists.some(containsId(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to iterate through lists array and check if object.id equals the requested ID.

```
checkID(id: number){
   for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    if(lists[i].id == id){
    return true;
     }
     else{
       return false;
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will return `true` if particularId found in list `false` otherwise.

```
const foundObjects = lists.filter(obj => obj.id == particularId)
return !foundObjects || foundObjects.length === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some, it will return true if the validation is true for at least one case.
Try something like this:

```
let myArray = [
{title: 'Title1', content: 'Content1', id: 10},
{title: 'Title2', content: 'Content2', id: 13},
{title: 'Title3', content: 'Content3', id: 14},
{title: 'Title4', content: 'Content4', id: 16},
]

myArray.some(function(el){ return (el.id === 10) ? true:false })
```